# How to make a range repeat n-times in Google SpreadSheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I use `ArrayFormula()` to simplify the way I create my reports.

Instead of having to create a reference in each cell (eg. `=C1`,`=C2`,`=C3`,`=C4` in each cell, I just use `=arrayformula(C1:C4)` in one single cell. It does exactly same job, but is much simpler and it keeps things more organized, because I just need to look in one cell for possible errors.

It works great when I have to reference a range into another like take the values of C1:C4 into the A1:A4 range. In the A1 cell I would just write `=arrayformula(C1:C4)` and it does its magic.

It does get a bit trickier when the ranges are not the same length, but it is feasible nonetheless. For instance, if I want to stack two or more range link C1:C4 on top of B1:B3, on cell A1 I can write `=arrayformula({C1:C4;B1:B3})`.

My problem is using `arrayFormula()` to copy a repeating pattern. For instance, if I want to copy the content of cell C1 4 times I would use `=arrayformula({C1;C1;C1;C1})`.

This would work and would achieve the desired effect. However, I was wondering if there is a better way to do that. Something like `=arrayformula({C1}*12)` were this pattern would repeat 12 times. This would also enable me to have a dynamic formula, such as `=arrayformula({C1}*count(D:D))` where the pattern would repeat according to some variable.

Do you have any ideia on how to achieve that using only native formula (no javascript)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For N_rows of **value**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(SEQUENCE(N_rows),value))
```

**value** can be anything here: a string, a number or a formula.

This was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70328566/3525368).

Here are some use cases:

N_rows can also be calculated with some other formula:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(SEQUENCE(COUNTIF(A:A,"Yes"),value))

You can also play with the condition of IF there:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISODD(SEQUENCE(N_rows)),"odd row","even row"))
```

or

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(SEQUENCE(N_rows)<3,"less than 3","greater than or equal 3"))
```

If you need a two-dimensional output:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(SEQUENCE(N_rows,M_columns),value))
```

You can also play with SEQUENCE parameters *start* and *step*.

See [SEQUENCE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244?hl=en).

#### Original answer:

For N rows and M columns of string **text**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA("text"&T(SEQUENCE(N_rows, M_columns)))
```

For N rows and M columns of number **123**:

```
=SEQUENCE(N_rows, M_columns, 123 ,0)
```

Answer (score 30):

I would use split() function instead of arrayformula() and rept() function to repeat cell positions. For example, if your n=4 the formula will look like this:

```
=split(rept(C1&";",4),";")
```

rept() repeats cell position C1+semicolon four times creating a string and split() function divides created string by semicolons to horizontal cells.

You can rotate resulted horizontal table to vertical table using transpose() function:

```
=transpose(split(rept(C1&";",4),";"))
```

And yes, you can use it to create dynamic formulas with help of arrayformula() function:

```
=arrayformula(count(D:D)*split(rept(C1&";",4), ";"))
```

Comment: Well, this solition requires your data to be text, and not to contain the separator you use...

Comment: @Olexa, the easy solution to that is to use a character almost never inputted, e.g. ¦ or ¬, as a delimiter.

Comment: it will still be text results, though, not necessarily numbers, if you need numbers

Answer (score 5):

Another way to do this is with `IF` and `SEQUENCE`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(SEQUENCE(4),C1))
```

Before sequence came, there was `ROW`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(A1:A4),C1))
```

The range `A1:A4` provides sequence of 1 to 4.

Answer (score 2):

```
=arrayformula(count(D:D)*split(rept(C1&";",4), ";"))
```

This approach won't work when C1 contains a Text Value.

I've come up with a variation to dynamically repeat / fill down a text value in-line with content from another column:

```
=arrayformula(transpose(split(rept("TEXT|",counta(D:D)), "|")))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the formula you're looking for is sequence with a zero step.

```
=sequence(12,1,3,0)
```

To make it dynamic, just make the number of rows your variable.

```
=sequence(count(d:d),1,3,0)
```