# How to use arrayformula to dynamically join strings in google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I use `Arrayformula()` to make my reports dynamic and easier to edit. For example, if I have a Column A with a list o number o blue balls in a set and a Column B with a list red balls in a set, on the cell C1 I can write `=ArrayFormula(add(A1:A,B1:B))` and in the Column C will have the total of balls in each set. It would be exactly the same as writing `=A1+B1` in cell C1 and dragging the formula down to the last row. `Arrayformula()` has some benefits, because it will work if some adds or removes rows from the sheet and also it makes the reports way more organized and easier to edit.

Since I´ve discovered `arrayformula()`, my life has changed, because of the fact that googleSheets expands the formula to other cells. It does not work every time, but the idea of expanding to other cells seems to be possible some way or another, [here is a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35037640/how-to-make-a-range-repeat-n-times-in-google-spreadsheet/35039281#35039281) of a problem that was not resolved by `arrayformula()`, but has the same idea.

Keeping that idea in mind, imagine that on Column A there is a list of First Names and on Column B there is a list of Last names. On Column C I want to join this two string using a simples space. The way to do that would be in the cell C1 write `=join(" ",A1,B1)` and then drag down this formula. This method method however is prone to error since people can add and remove rows, deleting my formula. I want to use a formula that I can write in one single cell and it expands to other cells. I´ve tried `=arrayformula(join(" ",A1:A,B1:B))`, but it does not work.

Is that a way to do that using `=arrayformula()` or other native function?

I know I could write a script or custom formula to do that, but this is not my goal here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this formula should work:

`=arrayformula(A1:A&" "&B1:B)`

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to use a delimiter, you can do the following to have a clean result even though, `A` or `B` is not present in some cases:

```
ARRAYFORMULA(ifna(ifs(isblank(A1:A),,ISBLANK(B1:B),A1:A),A1:A&" - "&B1:B))
```