# Is it possible to expand data in excel/googlesheets?

Tags: google-sheets

Here's an simplified example of what I am trying to do.

```
cat  2
dog  3
```

Translated to:

```
cat
cat
dog
dog
dog
```

Is that possible with just a function in a cell or do I have to use something like a macro? How would I do that?

Comment: Which is it? Excel or Google Sheets. They each work quite differently.

Comment: it's google sheets. My mistake, I thought they were similar enough for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Google sheets, assuming dog and cat are in A1 and A2 and 2 and 3 are in B1 and B2, this will do it:

```
=transpose(split(rept(A1&" ",B1)&rept(A2&" ",B2)," "))
```

Comment: Took me ages to figure out my version. Double or nothing on Excel;)

Answer (score 1):

In Google sheets, assuming "dog  2" and "cat 3" are in A1 and A2, this will do it:

```
=transpose(QUERY({(split(rept(split(A1," ")&" ",query(split(A1," "), "SELECT Col2"))," ")),(split(rept(split(A2," ")&" ",query(split(A2," "), "SELECT Col2"))," "))},,))
```

**Credit:**

[G4mo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5462626/g4mo) in StackOverflow [How to make a range repeat n-times in Google SpreadSheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35037640/how-to-make-a-range-repeat-n-times-in-google-spreadsheet)

Comment: This did work, though it is a bit more complicated than the other one which I marked as the answer.

Comment: @kschiek Point noted. It is a cumbersome formula and could be improved upon. But FWIW it also assumes a different starting position, where it is necessary to first split the text and number, and then to generate the list. EdNelson's answer is a thing of beauty and a joy to behold, and It may be useful for others at some future date to have both options.

Answer (score 1):

In Excel, you can use either `VLOOKUP()` or a combination of `INDEX()` and `MATCH()`.

With data in cols **A** and **B**, in **C1** enter 1 and in **C2** enter:

```
=C1+B1
```

and copy downward.  In **D1** enter:

```
=IF(ROWS($1:1)>SUM(B:B),"",INDEX(A:A,MATCH(ROWS($1:1),C:C,1)))
```

and copy downwards:

[image]

The helper column **D** translates the repetition factor in column **B** into match index.

*(Placing a helper column to the **left** of the data would allow the use of `VLOOKUP()`)*

Comment: this also worked, but was more complicated than the answer that I marked as my answer.